# Update to latest 5.15 kernel in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: kernel

as using ubuntu 20.04 ive been updating/upgrading kernel 5.4...
But as result of driver problems ive to install kernel >= 5.14, so now allowing installing development packages i the setup of update/upgrade manager, i could install kernel 5.15.0.25 ....
As i need my pc the most stable and secure possible i turned off the development packages again.
But when updatin/upgrading i get newer version of kernel 5.4.X but id need newer versions of 5.15 "branch" and not updating or upgrading the 5.4 "branch" any more....

So in fact i only need development packages for 20.04.4 LTS but only for kernel and possible collateral effects. How can i get it ?

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 is using the 5.4 kernel if you're using the GA kernel stack, and 5.13 if using the HWE stack currently; systems using HWE will upgrade to 5.15 in a ~month, but the *edge* kernel of HWE is for testing purposes and not stability. GA is the most stable (5.4) and it doesn't change.   `linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge | 5.15.0.28.29~20.04.8   | focal-proposed   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x`

Comment: I got kenrrel 5.15.0-25-generic, id like to pass to lowlatency....I got it enabling the developers option ( focal-propsed) ( updates not published yet)...So i disabled again, and id like to keep updated with 5.15 kernel....Thanks